# Time dependence of velocity from position dependece of velocity

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I know dependence of velocity on position $v(x)$ and I wan't to know dependence of velocity on time $v(t)$

I was thinking that using some chain rules or [derivative of inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_functions_and_differentiation) it would be possible to do it.

$\frac{d v(t)}{dt} = \frac{dv(x)}{dx} \frac{dx(t)}{dt} = \frac{dv(x)}{dx} v(t) $

but it is useless since I don't know neither $x(t)$ nor $v(t)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know the dependence of velocity on position.
Using $\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{dt}}=v(x)$, find position as a function of time, that is $x(t)$.

Then $v(x)$ is simply $\frac{dx}{dt}$.

Taking your example in the comments, suppose $v(x)=x^2+x$, we have
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=x^2+x$$
$$\frac{dx}{x(x+1)}=dt$$
$$\ln\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)=t+c$$
Where $c$ can be found by initial conditions.
$$\frac{x}{x+1}=c'e^t$$ where $c' = e^c$.
$$x=\frac{c'e^t}{1-c'e^t}$$
Then simply differentiate this with respect to time to get $v(t)$.

Comment: let's say $v(x) = x^2 + x $  how to integrate $\frac{dx(t)}{dt} = v(x) =  x^2 + x$ ?

Comment: aha, OK the actual function I have is a bit more complex $v(x) = \sqrt{ {C_1}( ( (x/{C_2}+1)^{C_3} - 1 } $ which is very hard to integrate analytically
Is this approch applicable for If I integrate $v(x)$ numerically

Comment: it could be perhaps simlified to
 $v(y) = \sqrt{ {C_2}*y^{C_3} - C_1 } $
by substiturion of $y = x + some const$

Answer (score 1):

What you get is an autonomous differential equation
$$
\dot x(t)=v(x(t)).
$$
The velocity at time $t$ obviously depends on the position $x$ at time $t$ and to get the latter functional dependence, you need to solve the differential equation.

Simple manipulation will not give the desired result.